# How can I use WillPopScope inside a Navigator in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

`WillPopScope`'s callback isn't being fired when I expected it to be. How can I use `WillPopScope` inside a `Navigator` so a route can handle it's own back pressed behaviour.

I'm learning to use flutter, and I came across `Navigator` for creating multiple pages (I know there are other navigation widgets but I'm after something which only supports programatic navigation so I can handle all the UI).

The next thing I thought to look at with the `Navigator` was going back, I found `WillPopScope` which wraps a component and has a callback that gets called when the back button is pressed (if the component is rendered). This seemed ideal for me since I only want the callback to be called if the Widget is rendered.

I tried to use `WillPopScope` within a `Navigator` with the intention for only the rendered route to have it's callback (`onWillPop`) called when the back button is pressed, but putting `WillPopScope` within a `Navigator` does nothing (the callback isn't called).

The intention is to have a `Navigator` navigate to top level routes and those routes themselves potentially having `Navigator`s, so putting `WillPopScope` inside means each route (or subroute) is responsible for it's own back navigation.

Many questions I've looked up seem to focus on `MaterialApp`, `Scaffold`, or other ways of handling navigation; I'm looking how to handle this without the UI that those things bring in (a use case could be a quiz app, where you need to click a next button to move forward, or something similar).

Here is the minimal `main.dart` file I expect route 2 to handle it's own back navigation (to keep things simple I've not put nested routes in this example).

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Navigation',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext parentContext) {
    return Container(
        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
        child: Navigator(
            initialRoute: "1",
            onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
              return PageRouteBuilder(pageBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                  Animation animation, Animation secondaryAnimation) {
                switch (settings.name) {
                  case "1":
                    return Container(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        child: GestureDetector(onTap: () {
                          debugPrint("going from 1 to 2");
                          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("2");
                        }));
                  case "2":
                    return WillPopScope(
                      child: Container(color: Colors.green),
                      onWillPop: ()async {
                        debugPrint("popping from route 2 disabled");
                        return false;
                      },
                    );
                  default:
                    throw Exception("unrecognised route \"${settings.name}\"");
                }
              });
            })
    );
  }
}
```

When the back button is pressed in either route 1 or 2, the app exits. I expect that to only be the case in route 1, and route 2 should only log `popping from route 2 disabled` (with no navigation away from the page or leaving the app).

From what I understand, `Navigator` and `WillPopScope` are the Widgets to use for this sort of thing, but if not then how would I implement self contained (potentially nested) routes.

Comment: If I get rid of my `Navigator` I make routes coupled to the root `MaterialApp`, not really an issue in the simple example I've given, but if in a bigger production app it wouldn't be ideal for two reasons. The first is that the `MaterialApp` can end up getting really big as the app grows, and the second is that routes become coupled to the `MaterialApp` Widget. Examples include onboarding routes that may want to be separate from other parts of the app, or a generic form for entering a persons details could pop up in a few places. That's is why I need to do this inside the `Navigator`.

Comment: If its something like a quiz app try using PageView you can generate as many pages as you want and handle the navigation from one page to the other

Comment: doesn't a `PageView` enable swipe navigation behaviour?

Comment: Yes it does and you can disable it if you want

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you create a Navigator you are automatically creating a new stack. Everything you `.push` below your Navigator using `Navigator.of(context)` is added to the new Navigator stack you just created. However, when you press the backbutton it doesn't know what you want to pop (if the root navigator or the new navigator).

First you need to add a WillPopScope outside your Navigator and add a NavigatorKey to your Navigator

```dart
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () => _backPressed(_yourKey),
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Navigator(
          key: _yourKey
          onGenerateRoute: _yourMaterialPageRouteLogic,
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: CustomNavigationBar(navBarOnTapCallback),
      ),
    );
```

Your key can be instatiated like this

```dart
    GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _yourKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
```

The `_backPressed` method will receive any backPressed you do on your device. By definition it returns `true`, and we don't always want to pop.

We've added a key to the navigator, and now it will be used to understand whether the new Navigator has anything in the stack in order to be popped (ie if it 'canPop').

```dart
Future<bool> _backPressed(GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _yourKey) async {
  //Checks if current Navigator still has screens on the stack.
  if (_yourKey.currentState.canPop()) {
    // 'maybePop' method handles the decision of 'pop' to another WillPopScope if they exist. 
    //If no other WillPopScope exists, it returns true
    _yourKey.currentState.maybePop();
    return Future<bool>.value(false);
  }
//if nothing remains in the stack, it simply pops
return Future<bool>.value(true);
```

Next you just need to add the WillPopScope anywhere inside your Navigator. Its `onWillPop` will be called with the logic you want. Don't forget to return true or false depending on whether you want to pop it or not :)

Here is a example of my `onWillPop` method (**_popCamera**) in a `WillPopScope` widget, which is placed inside my Navigator widget tree. In this example I've added a dialog when the user presses the back button in the Camera Widget:

```dart
  static Future<bool> _popCamera(BuildContext context) {
    debugPrint("_popCamera");
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (_) => ExitCameraDialog(),
        barrierDismissible: true);

    return Future.value(false);
  }

class ExitCameraDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  const ExitCameraDialog({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text('Leaving camera forever'),
      content:
      Text('Are you S-U-R-E, S-I-R?'),
      actions: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
          child: Text('no'),
          onPressed: Navigator.of(context).pop,
        ),
        FlatButton(
          //yes button
          child: Text('yes'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
            _yourKey.currentState.pop();
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Hope it's clear!

Comment: Thanks. This is the only answer that kind of made it more clear for me

Comment: At first you said: `First you need to add a WillPopScope outside your Navigator and add a NavigatorKey to your Navigator` and then you said: `Next you just need to add the WillPopScope anywhere inside your Navigator.` how come that ??

Comment: @JAHelia  There is one WillPopScope above the Navigator (it has a global key) and another one below the navigator wherever your use case needs it. "next" = WillPopScope below the navigator widget (like the one OP already had)

Answer (score 14):

You can forward onWillPop to another navigator by using below code:

```
onWillPop: () async {
    return !await otherNavigatorKey.currentState.maybePop();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Please can you explain to me why does it not wait without the exclamation mark?

Comment: maybePop() is returing `Future<bool>`. We're `await`ing for the future and the then negating the returned value.

Comment: Apparently the 'currentState' member could be null, which gives me this error: The method 'maybePop' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'. How do I get around that?